# Hide custom controls group on ribbon in word

Tags: vba, ms-word, office365, ribbon

Some background first. Im creating VBA script to transform one Word document into another one. I developed a script and put it into **dotm** template file.
First appication is using this template to export data. Next script in this template transforms exported data into new document. This template is also used to create result document. This means that all styles, scripts and custom ribbon UI is available in result document.
What I need is to remove scripts and custom ribbon UI from result document.
I was able to remove scripts but I don't know how to access and remove or hide custom ribbon UI from result document.
**Any hints?** Btw I don't want to put any script in result document which means that script from template have to delete or hide custom robbin UI from result document.

Comment: It's impossible to know what might work (or not) without knowing *how* the code is handling creating these various files. You should edit the question with a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

When you create the target document  Word will use the current attached template. You need to specify a different template e.g. Normal.dotm. (assuming you are not developing your scripts in Normal.dotm.

Comment: Yes, but still I would like to have **one-file-solution**. Your proposal means that I need two template files. I want to avoid it.

Comment: Your solution is already using two documents so its a minor change to create the second document using a different template.  It simplifies your task a great deal and also represents good practice in that you have seperated code from the document that you are processing.

Comment: No, my solution is using one document (scripts and styles). Second document is created based on the content contained in first document.
You propose to have separate template (two documents, one with script, second with styles) to produce result document.

Comment: No.  You copy styles from your template document to the new document using  "Application.OrganizerCopy source:=ActiveDocument.FullName, destination:=my_doc.FullName, Name:=my_style, Object:=wdOrganizerObjectStyles " in a loop.  The template creates the document, copies styles, copies and modifies content, but no need to worry about the ribbon provided you create the second document with a different template.  If you are worried about using two templates then create the template from your template, you just save the document as a dotm file.

Comment: @Jacek You say "Your proposal means that I need two template files. I want to avoid it. " But what Steven proposes is that you attach the docx that should "lose" the macros and ribbon to Normal.dotm. That's not "another" template file - that template is Word's default template and is always available in Word. `ResultDoc.AttachedTemplate = NormalTemplate`.

Comment: @StevenLaycock I change lots of build-in styles and I'm not able to copy them using OrganizerCopy. Or there is other quick way to overwrite build-in styles in new document?

Comment: In what way are you not able to copy styles.  What are the limitations you face.